# R : value not replaced in for loop with a function

Tags: r, list, loops, formattable

I am trying to create a list which I will then put into a function.

My problem is that "col" is never replaced by the increment variable (j). It remains "j". So at the end of my for loop when j is 11 all the col of all elements in the list are also j so 11 if I apply it to my function.

```
library(formattable)

x <- data.frame("value" = rep(1:5,2), "cats" = c(10,20,30,40,NA), "dogs" = c(15,25,35,36,48), "fish" = c(20,30,14,89,NA), "chicken"=c(14,23,12,9,3), "test"=c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE, TRUE,FALSE))

l=list()
for (j in 1:ncol(x)) {
  if (is.na(x[nrow(x),j])) {
    l[[j]]=area(row=1:(nrow(x)-1), col=j) ~ color_bar(color = "#E0E0E0", na.rm = TRUE)
  } 
  else {
    l[[j]]=area(row=1:(nrow(x)-1), col=j) ~ color_bar(color = "#99CCFF", na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}
l
formattable(x, l)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Help us help you: Provide an [mcve]. You've provided an example dataset in an easy format to use, and you've given most of your code, but as in the R tag info, please "specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls"

Comment: The only non-base package that I use is the formattable package. I've added a library call at the top. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because

> The  function  creates  an area object  to  store  the  representation  of  row  and  column  selector  expressions.    When  the  function  is  called,  the  expressions  and  environment  of row and column are captured for format_table to evaluate within the context of the input data.frame,  that is,rownames and colnames are  defined  in  the  context  to  be  the  indices  of  rows  and  columns,  respectively.   Therefore,  the  row  names  and  column  names  are  available  **symbols**  when row and col are evaluate

(emphasis added, from `help("area")`).

So it's accessing the value bound to the *symbol* `j`.

What you want to do instead is pass it a formula with the proper *value* of `j`:

```
l=list()
for (j in 1:ncol(x)) {
    if (is.na(x[nrow(x),j])) {
        print("yes")
        l[[j]] <- as.formula(
            paste("area(row=1:(nrow(x)-1), col=", j, ") ~ color_bar(",
                  "color = \"#E0E0E0\", na.rm = TRUE)")
        )
    } 
    else {
        print("no")
        l[[j]] <- as.formula(
            paste("area(row=1:(nrow(x)-1), col=", j, ") ~ color_bar(",
                  "color = \"#99CCFF\", na.rm = TRUE)")
        )
    }
}
l
formattable(x, l)
```

[image]

#### Update: Overall proportion

By default, with this approach, the size of the bars will be the within-column proportions. If you want overall proportions, you can pass a custom `fun` argument to `color_bar()` like so:

```
l=list()
for (j in 1:ncol(x)) {
    if (is.na(x[nrow(x),j])) {
        print("yes")
        l[[j]] <- as.formula(
            paste("area(row=1:(nrow(x)-1), col=", j, ") ~ color_bar(",
                  "color = \"#E0E0E0\",",
                  "fun = function(y) y / max(x, na.rm = TRUE))")
        )
    } 
    else {
        print("no")
        l[[j]] <- as.formula(
            paste("area(row=1:(nrow(x)-1), col=", j, ") ~ color_bar(",
                  "color = \"#99CCFF\",",
                  "fun = function(y) y / max(x, na.rm = TRUE))")
        )
    }
}
l
formattable(x, l)
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I would never have found it alone! Thank you very much !!!

Just one last question. Is there a way to have the bars colored while keeping the same proportion?

For example the first value of "value" is 1 and the first of "cats" is 10 but the bars have the same lengths.

It works when I only used one area () but with several I can't find the right option to get there.

Thanks again !

Comment: @fv8392 No worries, glad it helped! Added a change to allow for that

Comment: This is exactly what I needed ! Thank you very much !